# Word choice - "I consider X and Y as one of the most..."

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

I'm writing a Statement of Purpose of the graduate application and want to express my interest in the particular fields:

> I consider drug discovery and personalised healthcare as one of the most exciting applications of Bioinformatics.

Is this a correct way to say that? I'm concerned about using:

> I consider ... as one of the most...

with multiple subjects(drug discovery, personalised healthcare).

Thanks!

Comment: In contexts like this, ***as*** only really works with certain specific verbs (including ***regard, recognise, rate, acknowledge,...***). For ***consider, think***, etc., we almost always use the "subjunctive" construction as per *I know him **to be** honest*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects which you consider important, so the singular "one of the" won't do.

You could write

> I consider drug discovery and personalised healthcare to be the most
>   exciting applications of Bioinformatics.

Or less categorically:

> I consider drug discovery and personalised healthcare to be **among**
>   the most exciting applications of Bioinformatics.